# E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException:

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I am working with an Android-NDK project where i need to add `google-protobuf` library into my project.
My Project compiled and build/make project successfully and required `.so` file also get generated.But when i try to run my app, at run time i am getting following error and app crashed.

```
E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 3134 (...), pid 3134 (...)
```

google_protobuf version is 2.6.1.

**Note: I need to compile with this version only as my proto files are compiled with this only.So version i can not change**

> If you need more info about my issue, please ask in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution: Just want to share if someone face same kind of issue.
After digging deep in my project.

I found, i had two duplicate cpp files in my project.

Removed the culprit files.

`Build->Refresh Linked Cpp Projects
Build-> clean Project
Build-> Rebuild Project`

Works Fine without having issue.

Thanks

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

React-native zoom integration

The error I was having after using @minyushov provided solution was

assertion “terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_cast: std::bad_cast” failed

and it got resolved by solution provided by @majirosstefan

SoLoader.loadLibrary("zoom");
in MainApplication → onCreate